# Javascript - Navigation as a loop

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a simple navigation:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#div1">Div1-name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#div2">Div2-name</a></li>
    <li><a href="#div3">Div3-name</a></li>
</ul>
```

When clicked, it goes to the div with that id. I don't want to do this permanently, it's supposed to change in the loop because the user can add new items and wants them to be looped.

The user adds new div - with a unique name and ID. How to construct a loop?

It's best to set a constant class for divs (e.g. gohere), you have to load it via javascript, then do li elements in a loop.

Can anyone help?

And these are the elements that the user adds:

```
<div class="divdiv" id="div_id">
    <h3>DIV TITLE</h3>
    <br>
        Description
    <br>
    <p>Description</p>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you might need to clarify exactly what you mean, I'm struggling to understand this "loop". Are you talking about a carousel type component?

Comment: @DBS No. Listing items (ul / li) in a loop. Here is an example from PHP:             <?php foreach($pages->listed() as $item): ?>
      <li><a href="<?= $item->url() ?>"><?= html($item->title()) ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach ?>

Comment: So, are you are asking how to append elements to the DOM inside a JS loop? (If so, we will probably need to see the JS data structure you want to turn into elements)

Comment: @DBS I think so. User adds a div with a unique id and title. I want the loop in UL to list all the elements (i.e. the name of the new block + href to its ID).

Comment: Should the div element be added when the user clicks the menu item or is it two separate things?

Comment: @chrwahl two separate things, the user adds a lot of such div and at the top there is a navigation that scrolls to the given ID.

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep the navigation details in an array, and then iterate over it.
2. Use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse the HTML the user adds to extract the navigation information.

```js
const arr = [
  { href: "div1", name: 'Div1-name' },
  { href: "div2", name: 'Div2-name' },
  { href: "div3", name: 'Div3-name' }
];

const nav = document.querySelector('#nav');
const main = document.querySelector('#main');
const text = document.querySelector('textarea');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', handleInput, false);

const parser = new DOMParser();

function handleInput() {

  // Add the HTML to the page
  main.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', text.value);

  // Parse the HTML
  const frag = parser.parseFromString(text.value, 'text/html');
   
  // Extract the id (href) and name
  const href = frag.querySelector('div').id;
  const name = frag.querySelector('h3').textContent;

  // Add this to the navigation array
  // to the array
  arr.push({ href: `#${href}`, name: name });
  updateView();
}

function updateView() {

  // `map` is useful here. It will produce a new array
  // (of HTML), but make sure you `join` it up at the end
  const links = arr.map(({ href, name }) => {
    return `<li><a href="${href}">${name}</a></li>`;
  }).join('');
  nav.innerHTML = `<ul>${links}</ul>`;
}

updateView();
```

```html
<div id="nav"></div>
 
Add HTML:
<textarea></textarea>
<button>Add</button>

<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think I wrote it wrong. My English is poor. The user adds these items as BLOCKS in PRESTA. It just adds a diva with a unique title and ID. Only names are to appear in the navigation. So Javascript needs to get the ID / Title of these added items and loop them through as navigation.

Comment: So does the user just add that HTML in a text box, and you're asking how to grab the details from that HTML?

Comment: exactly yes :) user adds blocks from HTML. Of course, the title and ID change there. Navigation is a listing of the titles and IDs of these HTML blocks.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work :/ Most likely I misinterpret it. Could you compose this code just for element parsing? Without these buttons etc, this is not needed. Because I try and I have errors in the console. Can you test the code? And thank you again for your help.

Comment: I tested it with the HTML you supplied in your question, and it works fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, no elements are added to the array.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. [Here's a gif of me running the code](https://imgbox.com/jzxJGNdy). I add the HTML, the info gets added to the array, the navigation is updated. I then click on the new link and the document scrolls to the content.

Comment: It works here. It doesn't work with my blocks. User adds blocks to HTML (as separate blocks) and it doesn't work.

Comment: Button. I think it's a button. There can't be a button here.

Comment: It's only an example. I don't know anything about Presta.

Comment: The added elements are just HTML, no buttons etc. Just as if a new element is pasted. That's why I wrote about the loop that JavaScript takes the TITLE, ID from the div and lists them in UL.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it's really difficult to understand exactly what you ask for, but here (a bit hacky) an example. I hope that it can help you in the right direction.

```js
var items = document.getElementById('items');
var main = document.getElementById('main');

items.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target.nodeName == 'A') {
    console.log(`You clicked ${e.target.attributes['href'].value}`);
  }
});

document.forms.new.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let newid = items.children.length + 1;
  console.log(newid);
  let li = `<li><a href="#div${newid}">Div${newid}-name</a></li>`;
  items.innerHTML += li;
  let div = `<div class="divdiv" id="div${newid}">
    <h3>DIV TITLE</h3><br>Description<br><p>Description</p><hr></div>`;
  main.innerHTML += div;
});
```

```html
<ul id="items">
  <li><a href="#div1">Div1-name</a></li>
  <li><a href="#div2">Div2-name</a></li>
  <li><a href="#div3">Div3-name</a></li>
</ul>

<form name="new">
  <button>Add new</button>
</form>

<div id="main"></div>
```