# javascript Navigation (list), how to add elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I add blocks on one subpage - it's an HTML code. There are more and more of these blocks and I would like to make it easier for myself to navigate. The blocks are displayed one after the other. At the very top of the subpage there is "navigation" - the div title and the href = id div attribute.

Here is the "navigation" code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tips1">Tips - Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tips2">Tips 2 - How to</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tips3">Tips 3 - Hello World</a></li>
</ul>
```

And these are the blocks that I add (each has a different id and a different title in the h3 tag):

```
<div id="tips1">
    <h3>Tips - Lorem</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

I just add blocks as HTML code. How to make this navigation dynamic? Foreach loop?

Regards Jacob.

Comment: [I answered something similar today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67634549/javascript-navigation-as-a-loop/67635178?noredirect=1#comment119550881_67635178), but it was to do with Presta, but it might help you.

Comment: @Andy Thanks! This is a good code!

Answer (score 1):

This is my code for creating dynamic td inside table tag using foreach loop
please read this properly and I am sure it will help you

```
let myTr = document.getElementById("myTr");
let data = ['B','C'];

data.forEach(item => {
  let td = document.createElement("TD");
  td.innerHTML = item;
  myTr.appendChild(td);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain an array and use `map()` to iterate over and display. Or a `foreach()`. If you intend to use JavaScript

Comment: Recommend referring this. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp. You will need to research on how to create the HTML elements from JavaScript.